# Transport moving object/person to another video

Tags: video

For a video.How can i keep a moving person from a video,and move that person (moving person) to another video.I mean something like that

What software i need and what i have to do to accomplish that.

Comment: Welcome! Can you be more specific? What exactly are you trying to do? Is the video you shared an example of what you want to do or your source footage?

Answer (score 2):

The answer you're looking for is called "masking."

You can find this tool in the majority of professional editing software, but I personally recommend adobe after effects. There is also a chance that some of "moving objects/people" are already presented on green screens-- where as masking would usually be necessary, a "chroma key" would instead take the job.

Simply "cutting out" the moving figures isn't the only technique seen in this video. If you plan to execute a video in this fashion, you'll need to both cut out the "moving figure," but also motion track these figures onto the new composition. From there you'll need to manipulate their positions in order to make a convincing and visually appealing effect.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You need to rotoscope/mask the footage with After Effects you want to move and render with an alpha channel then overlay on to the other footage